# Superagent async nested loop http call

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to use superagent to get the link in table in webpage and get value from another table in that link.

So far I have succeed what I want in console.log but having problem trying to return the object with asynchronous call.

The first `await request` in `getData` function works fine but another one inside `getOrder` which also inside cheerio `.each` is not work as I expected.

*mention the cheerio here because I not sure what is cause the problem*

**Here what I've done so far**

```
const request = require('superagent');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

server.get('/crawler', (req, res) => {
  const data = await getData(url)
  console.log('data loaded ')
  res.send(data)
})

const getData = async (url) => {
  console.log('before root')
  const result = await request.get(url).set(header)
  console.log('after root')

  const $ = cheerio.load(result.text);

  let p = Promise.resolve();
  $('table').first().find('tr').each(async (i, row) => {
    p = p.then(async () => {
      console.log('order no', row.orderNo)
      let viewOrder = await getOrder(row.url)
      console.log('after getOrder')

      // .... build data here 

    })
  })
  p.then(() => {
    // ....
    return data
  })
}

const getOrder = async (url) => {
  console.log('before call')
  const result = await request.get(url).set(header)
  // the response return before this line in 1st round of loop 
  console.log('called', url)

  const $ = cheerio.load(result.text);

  let p = Promise.resolve();
  $('table').first().find('tr').each(async (i, row) => {
    p = p.then(async () => {
      // .... build data here
    })

  })
  p.then(() => {
    return data
  })
}
```

**Output**

```
before root
after root
order no 1
before call
data loaded
GET /crawler <<<<<<< res.send here
called ...
after getOrder
order no 2
before call
called ...
after getOrder
before call
order no 3
called ...
after getOrder
```

**What it should be**

Program should wait for all request is called then return the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found that I need to wrap the function in `Promise` and `resovle` it to make it work with `await`

```
const getData = (url) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('before root')
    const result = await request.get(url).set(header)
    console.log('after root')

    const $ = cheerio.load(result.text);

    let p = Promise.resolve();
    $(tableSelector).first().find('tr').each(async (i, row) => {
      p = p.then(async () => {
        console.log('order no', row.orderNo)
        let viewOrder = await getOrder(row.url)
        console.log('after getOrder')

        // .... build data here 

      })
    })
    p.then(() => {
      // ....
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}

const getOrder = async (url) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('before call')
    const result = await request.get(url).set(header)
    console.log('called', url)

    const $ = cheerio.load(result.text);

    let p = Promise.resolve();
    $(tableSelector).first().find('tr').each(async (i, row) => {
      p = p.then(async () => {
        // .... build data here
      })

    })
    p.then(() => {
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
function doSomething() {
  return () => 
    fetch('/api/something').then(response => response.json())
}

function doSomethingElse() {
  return () => 
    fetch('/api/something').then(response => response.json())
}

function doEverything() {
  return () => Promise.all([
   doSomething(),
   doSomethingElse()
  ]);
}
```

Comment: I need result from api1 to use to call api2 and the result is array, can you show me how to it properly ?

Comment: fetch('/api/something').then(response =>{ var result = response.json();fetch('/api/other api',{data: result.data}).then(response => response.json() ) })